# phpmyadmin printing php code, not executing

Tags: php

Running Linux Mint 21.  I did an apt install lamp^ to get apache, mysql etc.  I then installed phpmyadmin, apt install phpmyadmin.

/phpinfo.php works fine so php seems to be working however /phpmyadmin give me:
...

```
 <?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use PhpMyAdmin\Routing;

if (! defined('ROOT_PATH')) {
    // phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
    define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    // phpcs:enable
}

global $route, $containerBuilder;

require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/common.inc.php';

$dispatcher = Routing::getDispatcher();
Routing::callControllerForRoute($route, $dispatcher, $containerBuilder);
```

...

Comment: You are saying the PHP code is not being executed but instead displayed on the site?

Comment: Yes, but not all php code, just phpmyadin.

Comment: To the person that closed this.  This is different from the problem all 27 answers address.  As I said it's not a general php problem but specific to phpmyadmin.